# How to merge this dataframe in python?

Tags: python, r

Basically, i have this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/student-alcohol-consumption#student-merge.R.
As they said, i  have almost 400 students who belong to both datasets, whan can ruin my analysis.
To find them I have an instruction how to merge the table in R, but i would like to do the same in Python. How can i do that?

Code in R:

```
d1=read.table("student-mat.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE)
d2=read.table("student-por.csv",sep=";",header=TRUE)

d3=merge(d1,d2,by=c("school","sex","age","address","famsize","Pstatus","Medu","Fedu","Mjob","Fjob","reason","nursery","internet"))
print(nrow(d3)) # 382 students
```

Thank You in advance for all the help.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you using pandas? If so, have you looked into [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)?

Comment: PiotrK, while I do *not* think this is quite "off topic", I do believe that it is a little lacking (and still prone to closure due to "Needs details"). For example: sample unambiguous data; research into python; expected output. Questions are answered much more quickly and accurately when asked along the guidelines discussed in the links AMC provided.